# Keep transparency at end of file vim

Tags: vim, rxvt

I am using urxvt, when using vim the transparancy after the end of the file I am editing isn't working it is just a solid color with '~' on each line. This problem only happens when using a custom theme.

How do I get the transparancy back while keeping the theme?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, adding `hi NonText ctermbg=NONE` to .vimrc solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the way `urxvt` implements transparency. It adds another color, which it sets as the default background color, and which is the 'transparent' color. If you change that background color, then the bits that have a different background color are no longer transparent.

You have two options:

- stop changing your background color. Vim does have some themes that don't do this; in fact, I don't think I've seen this problem with any their except the "blue" one.
- change to a terminal emulator that implements transparency in a different way, which would not have that problem. I believe gnome-terminal fits that bill, though I am absolutely not a fan of that thing, for various reasons.